# Make a comparison and print out what is not in the list, how can I do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare

```
import re


Hosts = ["gvff", "etc"]



def list():
    with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/scripts/devices.txt', 'r') as file:
        for row in file:
            device = row.rsplit('\n')
            devices = re.search("^(.*?)\,(.*?)\,(.*?)\,", device[0])
            if devices != None:
                device = devices.group(1)
                hardwaretype = devices.group(2)
                level = devices.group(3)
                
                for host in Hosts:
                    if device.startswith(host):
                        if level == 'Production' or level == 'Production-Secondary':
                            print(f'| {device} | {hardwaretype} | {level} |')



list()
```

Hey I'm not getting anywhere at the moment. I want to compare the hosts list with the devices.txt. It currently prints me everything it has matched, but I need the items that could not be matched. How could I do that here?

Current Output: | blabla.bla.bla | physical | Production | this host is in the device.txt and in the Hosts list, so its the matching output

Excepted Output: looks like above, but only the hosts which are in devices.txt but not in Hosts List.

Many greetings

Comment: do you want to print devices having `level = production` or `level = production-secondary` but are not in the `hosts` list?

Comment: Yes. Their are many Hosts in the Host list, the above are just an example. And I want to print all Hosts which are not in the Hosts list but are in the device.txt and only the hosts with the level

Comment: can you provide how devices.txt file looks like

Comment: I pasted an example into the comment section

Comment: please add expected output and current output in your question

Comment: Hii @OP, can you print the device and host before the line if device.startswith(host):? And also, share the content of device.txt. It'll be easy to analyse.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `not` keyword before `device.startswith(host)`, it will make the condition `true` if the `device` not starts with 'host' otherwise `false`.

**change**

```
if device.startswith(host):
   ...
```

**to**

```
if not device.startswith(host):
   ...
```

Comment: I tried, but it prints all hosts from the device list. Not working :(